# PopupMenu в ListView. Неправильно расположение

Tags: android

Всем привет уважаемые форумчане. У меня возникла такая проблема которую я не могу решить уже неделю. Она заключается в следующем. Есть ListView, и в каждом item-е на его нажатие было прописано так, чтобы вылазило PopupMenu,но проблема в том, что когда нажимаешь на нижний item то они показываются неправильно. Подробности ниже:
**Исходный ListView до нажатия**:
[image]

**ListView после нажатия**:

[image]

Т.е косяк в том, что когда я нажал на 4 item и показалось popup menu,то после этого произошол скролл вниз на одну item. Так же происходит когда нажимаешь на item 3. Когда нажимаешь на 1 или 2, то всё нормально. Может кто сталкивался, подскажите как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: отправь код ! Посмотрим!

Comment: @Дройдер если не хочешь получить бан - следи за "базаром". Ответ это ответ, а комментарий это комментарий

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).